# Are there hybrids that emerge as a new species?

Tags: zoology

We know a couple of hybride (mammal) animals (http://www.rantpets.com/2015/06/03/15-strangest-hybrid-animal-breeds-you-didnt-know-existed/) and perhaps even more and perhaps even insects like the Drosophila.

But are there animals which arise as a new species? And by species I mean animals who can't breed with the species of their parents but can interbreed succesfully with their own species ('brothers' and 'sisters'). Only leaving out pre-mating mechanisms in case they don't get offspring (so that only Post-mating isolating mechanisms counts)

See also: [Have we ever observed two drosophila lineages that evolved reproductive isolation in labs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/have-we-ever-observed-two-drosophila-lineages-that-evolved-reproductive-isolatio)
[Have scientists ever produce a new species in laboratory by means of natural selection?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42581/have-scientists-ever-produce-a-new-species-in-laboratory-by-means-of-natural-sel)

Comment: While it is an interesting question, since the operational definition of species is the inability to interbreed with other species, the fact that hybrids are viable suggests the two initial "species" are almost the same.  By post-mating I assume that you mean chromosomal problems during meiosis (e.g., aneuploid gametes)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called [**hybrid speciation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_speciation).

> Hybrid speciation is a form of speciation wherein hybridization between two different species leads to a new species, reproductively isolated from the parent species

There has been a fair amount of work on hybrid speciation (see [here](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=hybrid%20speciation&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)). Hybrid speciation is often thought to be more frequent in plants than animals. In ferns for example, we estimate that 7% of species emerged through hybrid speciation ([Otto and Whitton 2000](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~otto/reprints/OttoWhitton2000.pdf)). Typical cases of hybrid speciation include changes in ploidy levels (examples include sunflowers). Hybrid speciation also occurs in animals such as the [lonicera fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonicera_fly) to cite just an example.

Comment: In my initially question I asked (before it was edited) species created by human. Are new species created by human?

Comment: The post did not match the title (the post made absolutely no reference to humans). Now that the broad question of "is this a thing" has been answered I would recommend that you open a new post to ask specifically about humans. You will be able to use the term hybrid speciation which will make your post short and clear.